# How to convert early bound query to IQueryable<TEntity>

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dynamics-crm-2011

Assuming that `AccountSet` returns an `IQueryable<Account>`, how can I convert this early binding:

```
XrmServiceContext _xrmServiceContext;
var result = _xrmServiceContext.AccountSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == locationGuid);
```

Into something that is more reusable like:

```
_xrmServiceContext.Where(Set == "Account").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == locationGuid);
```

`AccountSet` is defined as:

```
    public System.Linq.IQueryable<Xrm.Account> AccountSet
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CreateQuery<Xrm.Account>();
        }
    }
```

**How do I generalize this to be reusable for any `IQueryable` member of `XrmServiceContext` ?**

Comment: this is similar to what i would like to do but it uses reflection, something that  i want to avoid, http://stackoverflow.com/a/38198824/6761907

Answer (score 1):

As long as the Id is the primary key you can use that in conjunction with find to make a generic call

```
public T Get<T>(object[] Id)
      where T : class
{
    return _xrmServiceContext.Set<T>().Find(Id )
}
```

if your looking for an IQueryable that may be a bit harder but you can find out how to do that off of a previous question I asked:

[Entity Framework Filter By PrimaryKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240968/entity-framework-filter-by-primarykey)

Comment: but it could be Xrm.Account, or Xrm.Contact, or a lot of other classes

Comment: The set function looks up the db set based off of its entity type

Comment: this is similar to what i want to do but it uses reflection http://stackoverflow.com/a/38198824/6761907

Comment: @MeggieLuski  what are you confused about here,  the type passed into the set is generic so you create a generic function get<T> and that passes to to the context and gets the entity set

Comment: there's no "set" method

Comment: You might just be missing a using hit ctrl . On the red underline see if there is an add using

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy of [this](https://csharpsql.wordpress.com/tag/xrm/) post, I've found the following solution:

```
private static T EntityGet<T>(Guid id)
    where T : Entity
{
    T item =
    (
        from query in Context.CreateQuery<T>()
        where query.Id == id
        select query
    ).Single();

    return item;
}
```

Comment: How are you to specify that T has an id

Comment: T is an Entity, and Entity has id